# Trouble with PHP's MySQLI flag MYSQL_PRI_KEY_FLAG

Tags: php, mysqli, indexing

I came across a strange behaviour and want to know if I am doing a misstake or the API is indeed working this way.

I am talking about MYSQLI, my own PHP frameowrk can analyze the table to build a dynamic Entity class out of it which works very well so far, however im struggling with the MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG which should tell me if the column's index is part of a PRIMARY_KEY index.

However given is the following table:

```
ip_ranges
```

cols are:

```
account_id, min, max, comment
```

The only index on this table is a unique index with name:

```
account_id_unique
```

and over 3 columns:

```
account_id, min, max
```

There is definetly no PRIMARY_KEY defined.

---

So far so good, the last info you need is that the array $this->columns contains all columns data fetched with:

```
Mysqli_Result::fetch_fields
```

Now I use the following 2 member functions to determine if a column has the flag PRIMARY_KEY:

```
    public function columnHasFlag($columnName, $flag) {
        $retVal = false;

        if(isset($this->columns[strtolower($columnName)]) == true && $this->columns[strtolower($columnName)]["flags"] & $flag) {
            $retVal = true;
        }

        return $retVal;
    }

    public function determinePrimaryKeyColumn() {
        if($this->columnPrimaryKey === null) {
            foreach($this->columns as $columnName => $data) {
                if($this->columnHasFlag($columnName, MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG) == true) {
                    $this->columnPrimaryKey = $columnName;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The strange this is that I get for the example table above, when I use 'vardump' on $this->columns[strtolower($columnName)]["flags"] which contains the flags for the column "account_id" it returns me the value: "int(49155)"

and columnHasFlag returns me "true" for statement:
    $this->columns[strtolower($columnName)]["flags"] & $flag

($flag evaluates the constant MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_VALUE which evaluates to "2".

---

So how it is possible that the flag is set? I thought this flag is only set for the PRIMARY key index which must have the name primary? Or is it set for any other UNIQUE_KEY aswell?

However, this seems rather strange because there are seperate flags for UNIQUE and the PRIMARY key in the mysqli_result::fetch_field documentation:

```
NOT_NULL_FLAG = 1
PRI_KEY_FLAG = 2
UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG = 4
...
(http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)
```

So my question, is this a bug or am I comparing the flags wrong somehow?
Or did I miss something in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a bug, here is a quote from [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

> A UNIQUE index may be displayed as PRI if it cannot contain NULL
>   values and there is no PRIMARY KEY in the table. A UNIQUE index may
>   display as MUL if several columns form a composite UNIQUE index;
>   although the combination of the columns is unique, each column can
>   still hold multiple occurrences of a given value.

This is the code that I used to test that behavior.

```
$flags = array( 'NOT_NULL_FLAG'          => MYSQLI_NOT_NULL_FLAG,                                                                      
                'PRI_KEY_FLAG'          => MYSQLI_PRI_KEY_FLAG,                                                                       
                'UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG'       => MYSQLI_UNIQUE_KEY_FLAG, 
                'MULTIPLE_KEY_FLAG'     => MYSQLI_MULTIPLE_KEY_FLAG,                    
                'BLOB_FLAG'             => MYSQLI_BLOB_FLAG,                                                                          
                'UNSIGNED_FLAG'         => MYSQLI_UNSIGNED_FLAG,                                                                      
                'ZEROFILL_FLAG'         => MYSQLI_ZEROFILL_FLAG,                                                                      
                'BINARY_FLAG'           => MYSQLI_BINARY_FLAG,                                                                        
                'ENUM_FLAG'             => MYSQLI_ENUM_FLAG,                                                                          
                'AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG'   => MYSQLI_AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG,                                                                
                'TIMESTAMP_FLAG'        => MYSQLI_TIMESTAMP_FLAG,                                                                     
                'SET_FLAG'              => MYSQLI_SET_FLAG,                                                                           
                'PART_KEY_FLAG'         => MYSQLI_PART_KEY_FLAG,                                                                      
                'NUM_FLAG'              => MYSQLI_NUM_FLAG );

function info_array( $result ) {
    return array_reduce( $result->fetch_fields(), function( $result, $info ) {
        $result[ $info->name ] = $info;
        return $result;
    } );
}

function get_flags( $meta, $flags ) {
    return array_filter( $flags, function( $flag ) use ( $meta ) {
        return $meta->flags & $flag;
    } );
}

$result = $mysqli->query( 'SELECT * FROM ip_ranges LIMIT 1' );

$column_flags = array();
foreach( info_array( $result ) as $name => $value ) {
    $column_flags[ $name ] = get_flags( $value, $flags );
}

print_r( $column_flags );
```

So I created a table in DB with unique index over 3 columns an got an output like you said, all 3 columns have primary key flag set.

```
Array (
    [account_id] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1
         [PRI_KEY_FLAG] => 2
         [PART_KEY_FLAG] => 16384
         [NUM_FLAG] => 32768 )
    [min] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1
         [PRI_KEY_FLAG] => 2
         [PART_KEY_FLAG] => 16384
         [NUM_FLAG] => 32768)
    [max] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1
         [PRI_KEY_FLAG] => 2
         [PART_KEY_FLAG] => 16384
         [NUM_FLAG] => 32768 )
    [comment] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1 )

)
```

A show columns query ( `SHOW COLUMNS FROM ip_ranges` ) in mysql admin got me the same result.

```
Field       Type      Null   Key    Default    Extra
account_id  int(11)   NO     PRI    NULL    
min         int(11)   NO     PRI    NULL    
max         int(11)   NO     PRI    NULL    
comment     varchar() NO            NULL
```

Then I created a primary key, and got the following output:

```
Array (
    [id] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1
         [PRI_KEY_FLAG] => 2
         [AUTO_INCREMENT_FLAG] => 512
         [PART_KEY_FLAG] => 16384
         [NUM_FLAG] => 32768 )
    [account_id] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1
         [MULTIPLE_KEY_FLAG] => 8
         [PART_KEY_FLAG] => 16384
         [NUM_FLAG] => 32768
        )
    [min] => Array(
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1
         [PART_KEY_FLAG] => 16384
         [NUM_FLAG] => 32768 )
    [max] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1
         [PART_KEY_FLAG] => 16384
         [NUM_FLAG] => 32768 )
    [comment] => Array (
         [NOT_NULL_FLAG] => 1 )
)
```

```
Field       Type      Null  Key     Default     Extra
id          int(11)   NO    PRI     NULL    auto_increment
account_id  int(11)   NO    MUL     NULL    
min         int(11)   NO            NULL    
max         int(11)   NO            NULL    
comment     varchar() NO            NULL
```

So in the end, the php and mysql are reporting the same thing.

Comment: Ok, on the one hand I don't really like that behaviour because it is not exact but on the other hand I think it is enough for my framework if this flag ensures that the column with the flag is definetly atleast treated as unique key. This should be reliable enough for my purpose. Looks like for a more detailed information I need to query the indizes myself and analyse the table structure manually. However thanks for the effort, now I know that I am not making a misstake reading the flag and its not a "bug" either.