# How check a Field Statement is NOT NULL with mysqli on php?

Tags: php, mysqli

In php 4+ at 5.5, i can use the mysql_fetch_field for checker if field is NOT_NULL on column statement. Like this:

```
$meta = mysql_fetch_field($result);
$meta->not_null; // HERE RETORN -1 IF COLUMN IS DEFINED AS NOT NULL IN MYSQL STATEMENT
```

How i can get this param with  **mysqli_any_thing**? 
Because mysql_fetch_field is deprecated!

I search for this in php.net but I did not find.

**SOLUTION ARE HERE:** 
[Trouble with PHP's MySQLI flag MYSQL_PRI_KEY_FLAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358567/trouble-with-phps-mysqli-flag-mysql-pri-key-flag)

Comment: There is `fetch_field` in mysqli.

Comment: I found this , and solve ! Thank you
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Comment: Great!, happy coding :)